# Load time weaving in AspectJ using aop.xml

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, load-time-weaving

From what I understand, for load time weaving to work using an aop.xml file, it must be placed in META-INF. Is there a way to get around this and use an aop.xml (or any xml file) in any directory? Thanks.

Comment: Why not stick with the standard location?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the system property `org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration` to point to another AspectJ config file. For example:

```
-Dorg.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration=file:META-INF/myaop.xml
```