# aop.xml name and location?

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, load-time-weaving

Is there a way to specify the name of the aop.xml file with LTW? or define another name and location?
I have several software modules that I use and that all use META-INF/aop.xml with different settings.
I include these modules in a web application and then it all dependens how it's deployed/unpacked, which aop.xml file is used ..
So I discovered after long time of searching that not all LTW weaving toke place correcting as it depends with aop.xml was used ...

Basically I need to use both aop.xml files, kinda of merging both contents of the aop.xml files...

How to do this?
Ed

Comment: Are the aop.xml files Spring Configuration files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using AspectJ you can use the system property `org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration` to point to another config file. For example:

```
-Dorg.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration=file:META-INF/myaop.xml
```

Comment: `-Dorg.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration=file:META-INF/myaop.xml` [#](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.aspectj/com.springsource.org.aspectj.tools/1.6.6/org/aspectj/weaver/loadtime/ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor.java#214)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [Load time weaving in AspectJ using aop.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314953/load-time-weaving-in-aspectj-using-aop-xml).

Furthermore, the [AspectJ documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html) says:

> When several configuration files are visible from a given weaving
>   class loader their contents are conceptually merged.