# AspectJ inside a testing framework

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, katalon-studio, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm trying to apply a cross cutting concern which is logging with AspectJ and a test framework called Katalon which uses Groovy and Java. I found that the best weaving type appropriate here is load-time weaving which requires a META-INF folder and an Aop.xml. I tried to put my aop.xml in multiple places but I think aspectj is unable to find it.
This is the structure of my project:

[image]

Here is my aop.xml file content:

```xml
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.fd.common.aspectName"/>
        <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
            <include within="com.myapp.common.*"/>
        </weaver>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

And here is my aspect :

```java
@Aspect
public class test {
    @org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before("execution(* *.*(..))")
    public void bef (JoinPoint jp) {
        System.out.println(jp.getSignature());
        System.out.println("Beforeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more careful when writing questions next time, your inline image was not visible. I fixed that for you and also added syntax highlighting to your code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess, not having seen your real project, is that you should move the weaver options out of the aspect declaration section like this:

```xml
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.fd.common.aspectName"/>
    </aspects>
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <include within="com.myapp.common.*"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

If this does not help, I need more information. I have never used Katalon before, so I need to inspect your exact project setup - of course not your full original project, if proprietary. But please prepare an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problem, publish it on GitHub and I can take a look for you. I need to see how you call java and what is logged to the console.

---

**Update:** There was a follow-up question about how to use system property `org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration` in order to point to an alternative resource URL or file system path name. I answered the same question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25404239/1082681) and have just updated it with some more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried what you mentioned but it's not working as well. For the VM arguments are these one correct

Comment: -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration=/Users/sam/Downloads/myProject_V2.7.6/META-INF/aop.xml
-javaagent:/Users/sam/Downloads/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar

Comment: Yes I wanted to mention in my comment that I'm going to do an MCVE but I want to ask my manger first then I pressed enter by mistake

Comment: I will post my github code here if okay, thank you.

Comment: FYI, I deleted my previous comments in favour of updating my answer, because SO is not a discussion forum and formatting is also easier in a question or answer.